# Unable to update Materialize.css tooltips using jQuery after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, materialize

I am using Materialize.css on my portfolio site, and am using the npm package clipboard.js. I am using this within a floating action button, and the copy to clipboard functionality is working as intended (when user clicks the button, it copies my email to their clipboard like it should).

However, I want the tooltip to update from ""Click to copy my email to your clipboard!" to a success message like "Copied to your clipboard ✅". I have tried the code below and it won't actually update the page, though I can sometimes see the new message (it's just very inconsistent, which I don't want).

This is my html element:

```
<li>
 <a id="email" data-clipboard-text="example@gmail.com" class="btn-floating red waves-effect waves-light tooltipped" data-position="left" data-tooltip="Click to copy my email to your clipboard!"><i class="material-icons">mail</i></a>
</li>
```

and here's my javascript:

```
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('#email');

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        var anchorElement = $('#email');
        anchorElement.attr('data-tooltip', 'Copied to your clipboard ✅');
        anchorElement.addClass('success');
        anchorElement.tooltip();

        // Reset after a timeout
        anchorElement.mouseleave(function() {

            setTimeout( function(){
                anchorElement.attr('data-tooltip', 'Click to copy my email address to your clipboard!');
                anchorElement.removeClass('success');
                anchorElement.tooltip();
            }, 300);
        });

        e.clearSelection();
    });
```

I would like for the tooltip to show the updated value consistently, but I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong with the code I have. I can tell that it does update the html element, as I can sometimes see the updated text, but it's very inconsistent and for this feature to be worth using at all I need it to be very consistent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that materialize.css adds in other DOM elements that eventually appear on screen as the tooltips themselves - elements that you aren't targeting right now - elements that you didn't write in your HTML. You're targeting the original data-attributes that materialize.css uses to create those other elements. Updating those data-attributes after render is too little too late... by then, the materialize.css library has already looked at those attributes and gotten what it needs.

If you look at the [official docs page](https://materializecss.com/tooltips.html) on tooltips, we can investigate a little on that page. Open your dev console and scroll towards the bottom you'll see four DOM elements with the class `material-tooltip` - these were added by the library, and these are the DOM elements that actually get shown on screen.

[image]

Open those `div`s up and watch what happens to them when you mouse over the Bottom, Top, Left, Right buttons on the screen. As each tooltip appears, you should notice that the message-to-be-displayed gets injected as text into that element, and it animates some CSS properties.

If you want to change the text being displayed, you can probably skip editing the data-attributes (*though if the library occasionally refreshes the content, changing the attributes might still be a good idea*)... instead, we need to edit the text being shown in ^^THESE^^ elements.

If you only have one tooltip being displayed on that page, it should be as simple as something like this:

```
$('.material-tooltip').innerText = 'Copied to your clipboard ✅'
```

or if you have multiple on that page, you can attempt to identify which `div` is for which tooltip, but I suspect that could end up being unreliable. It would probably be safer to update ALL of the `div`s... the library will overwrite the content anyways next time it renders... which again, it gets from your data-attributes. Updating all of them would look something like:

```
$('.material-tooltip').each( eachDiv => {
    eachDiv.innerText = 'Copied to your clipboard ✅'
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response! I hadn't realized where or how those hidden divs that actually contain the tooltip itself were being stored on my page. Upon further inspection, I realized that the text itself is actually displayed within a <span> tag contained within the <div> with a class of .material-tooltip. I think I will need to do some more fiddling with my jQuery selectors, but your answer has definitely put me on the right track. Much appreciated!

Comment: Now fully functional, I had to use this to select for the text within the span, and I was able to use similar javascript to what I was using before only with even fewer lines of code:                                                                                                        
`var tooltipText = $('.material-tooltip span')`                                                                          `tooltipText.html('Copied to your clipboard ✅')`

Answer (score 0):

here's only solution I found that works for me .. disclaimer - it's a bit hacky, basically it destroys tooltip on click and rebuilds it with new attr, then after a timeOut resets it back.

```
$('#shareLink').on('click', function (e) {
  
  $('#shareLink').tooltip('dispose').removeClass('material-tooltip').attr('title', 'Link copied!');
  $('#shareLink').addClass('material-tooltip').tooltip('show');

  setTimeout( function () {
    $('#shareLink').tooltip('dispose').removeClass('material-tooltip').attr('title', 'Copy link to Clipboard');
    $('#shareLink').addClass('material-tooltip').tooltip('enable');
  }, 2000);

});
```